# How do I change the font color and weight of gVim's command line (in the bottom)?

Tags: colors, vim

When you type a "Not an editor command", below of that it says: "Press ENTER or type command to continue, and it is bold and green. " It is possible to change the color and weight of that line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for gui: `:hi Question guifg=Blue gui=bold`

for term: `:hi Question ctermfg=Blue term=bold`